# Google PubSub with Ktor

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, ktor

I have been using Ktor for a while now and I want to integrate Google PubSub to Ktor but it is not working. When the app starts and PubSub is able to run, Ktor server fails to start.

I would appreciate anyone who has done has successfully integrated PubSub with Ktor to share with me how they were able to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Error Log after which PubSub runs well but Ktor dies off:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Reflective setAccessible(true) disabled
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil.trySetAccessible(ReflectionUtil.java:31)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$4.run(PlatformDependent0.java:238)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0.<clinit>(PlatformDependent0.java:232)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.isAndroid(PlatformDependent.java:289)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.<clinit>(PlatformDependent.java:92)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.AsciiString.<init>(AsciiString.java:223)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.AsciiString.<init>(AsciiString.java:210)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.AsciiString.cached(AsciiString.java:1401)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.AsciiString.<clinit>(AsciiString.java:48)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:74)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.<clinit>(NettyChannelBuilder.java:81)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider.builderForAddress(NettyChannelProvider.java:38)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider.builderForAddress(NettyChannelProvider.java:24)
    at io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(ManagedChannelBuilder.java:39)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:306)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.access$1600(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:73)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider$1.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:214)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.create(ChannelPool.java:72)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:221)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:204)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:169)
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.stub.GrpcSubscriberStub.create(GrpcSubscriberStub.java:272)
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber.doStart(Subscriber.java:276)
    at com.google.api.core.AbstractApiService$InnerService.doStart(AbstractApiService.java:148)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractService.startAsync(AbstractService.java:248)
    at com.google.api.core.AbstractApiService.startAsync(AbstractApiService.java:120)
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber.startAsync(Subscriber.java:268)
    at com.fbistech.ApplicationKt.listenToSub(Application.kt:314)
    at com.fbistech.ApplicationKt.access$listenToSub(Application.kt:1)
    at com.fbistech.ApplicationKt$main$started$1$1.invokeSuspend(Application.kt:96)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:277)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:86)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:61)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at com.fbistech.ApplicationKt$main$started$1.invoke(Application.kt:96)
    at com.fbistech.ApplicationKt$main$started$1.invoke(Application.kt)
    at io.ktor.application.ApplicationEvents.raise(ApplicationEvents.kt:46)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.safeRiseEvent(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:192)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.instantiateAndConfigureApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:311)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.createApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:136)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.start(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:268)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationEngine.start(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:174)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(EngineMain.kt:26)
    at com.fbistech.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:65)
2021-05-10 05:22:39.918 [main] DEBUG i.g.n.s.i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Bits.unaligned: available, true
2021-05-10 05:22:39.919 [main] DEBUG i.g.n.s.i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent0 - jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray(int): available
2021-05-10 05:22:39.919 [main] DEBUG i.g.n.s.i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, int): unavailable
2021-05-10 05:22:39.919 [main] DEBUG i.g.n.s.i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent - sun.misc.Unsafe: available
2021-05-10 05:22:39.930 [main] DEBUG i.g.n.s.i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent - maxDirectMemory: 4294967296 bytes (maybe)
2021-05-10 05:22:39.930 [main] DEBUG i.g.n.s.i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.tmpdir: /var/folders/g1/4bwcs52n38b3bcjc3rdv2zvm0000gn/T (java.io.tmpdir)
2021-05-10 05:22:39.930 [main] DEBUG i.g.n.s.i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.bitMode: 64 (sun.arch.data.model)
2021-05-10 05:22:39.931 [main] DEBUG i.g.n.s.i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory: -1 bytes
2021-05-10 05:22:39.931 [main] DEBUG i.g.n.s.i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.uninitializedArrayAllocationThreshold: 1024
2021-05-10 05:22:39.931 [main] DEBUG i.g.n.s.i.n.u.internal.CleanerJava9 - java.nio.ByteBuffer.cleaner(): available
2021-05-10 05:22:39.931 [main] DEBUG i.g.n.s.i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: false
2021-05-10 05:22:39.971 [main] DEBUG i.g.n.s.i.n.u.i.NativeLibraryLoader - -Dio.netty.native.workdir: /var/folders/g1/4bwcs52n38b3bcjc3rdv2zvm0000gn/T (io.netty.tmpdir)
2021-05-10 05:22:39.971 [main] DEBUG i.g.n.s.i.n.u.i.NativeLibraryLoader - -Dio.netty.native.deleteLibAfterLoading: true
2021-05-10 05:22:39.971 [main] DEBUG i.g.n.s.i.n.u.i.NativeLibraryLoader - -Dio.netty.native.tryPatchShadedId: true
2021-05-10 05:22:39.972 [main] DEBUG i.g.n.s.i.n.u.i.NativeLibraryLoader - Unable to load the library 'io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_osx_x86_64', trying other loading mechanism.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_osx_x86_64 in java.library.path: /Users/fbistech-d6m/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2447)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1893)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:371)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:363)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:341)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:136)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:96)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.loadTcNative(OpenSsl.java:590)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.<clinit>(OpenSsl.java:136)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.defaultSslProvider(GrpcSslContexts.java:228)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:145)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.forClient(GrpcSslContexts.java:94)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$DefaultProtocolNegotiator.newNegotiator(NettyChannelBuilder.java:594)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.buildTransportFactory(NettyChannelBuilder.java:500)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyChannelTransportFactoryBuilder.buildClientTransportFactory(NettyChannelBuilder.java:171)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(ManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:608)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:261)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:340)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.access$1600(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:73)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider$1.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:214)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.create(ChannelPool.java:72)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:221)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:204)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:169)
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.stub.GrpcSubscriberStub.create(GrpcSubscriberStub.java:272)
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber.doStart(Subscriber.java:276)
    at com.google.api.core.AbstractApiService$InnerService.doStart(AbstractApiService.java:148)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractService.startAsync(AbstractService.java:248)
    at com.google.api.core.AbstractApiService.startAsync(AbstractApiService.java:120)
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber.startAsync(Subscriber.java:268)
    at com.fbistech.ApplicationKt.listenToSub(Application.kt:314)
    at com.fbistech.ApplicationKt.access$listenToSub(Application.kt:1)
    at com.fbistech.ApplicationKt$main$started$1$1.invokeSuspend(Application.kt:96)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:277)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:86)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:61)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at com.fbistech.ApplicationKt$main$started$1.invoke(Application.kt:96)
    at com.fbistech.ApplicationKt$main$started$1.invoke(Application.kt)
    at io.ktor.application.ApplicationEvents.raise(ApplicationEvents.kt:46)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.safeRiseEvent(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:192)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.instantiateAndConfigureApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:311)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.createApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:136)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.start(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:268)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationEngine.start(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:174)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(EngineMain.kt:26)
    at com.fbistech.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:65)
2021-05-10 05:22:39.973 [main] DEBUG i.g.n.s.i.n.u.i.NativeLibraryLoader - io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_osx_x86_64 cannot be loaded from java.library.path, now trying export to -Dio.netty.native.workdir: /var/folders/g1/4bwcs52n38b3bcjc3rdv2zvm0000gn/T
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_osx_x86_64 in java.library.path: /Users/fbistech-d6m/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2447)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1893)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:351)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:136)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:96)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.loadTcNative(OpenSsl.java:590)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.<clinit>(OpenSsl.java:136)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.defaultSslProvider(GrpcSslContexts.java:228)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:145)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.forClient(GrpcSslContexts.java:94)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$DefaultProtocolNegotiator.newNegotiator(NettyChannelBuilder.java:594)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.buildTransportFactory(NettyChannelBuilder.java:500)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyChannelTransportFactoryBuilder.buildClientTransportFactory(NettyChannelBuilder.java:171)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(ManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:608)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:261)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:340)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.access$1600(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:73)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider$1.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:214)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.create(ChannelPool.java:72)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:221)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:204)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:169)
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.stub.GrpcSubscriberStub.create(GrpcSubscriberStub.java:272)
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber.doStart(Subscriber.java:276)
    at com.google.api.core.AbstractApiService$InnerService.doStart(AbstractApiService.java:148)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractService.startAsync(AbstractService.java:248)
    at com.google.api.core.AbstractApiService.startAsync(AbstractApiService.java:120)
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber.startAsync(Subscriber.java:268)
    at com.fbistech.ApplicationKt.listenToSub(Application.kt:314)
    at com.fbistech.ApplicationKt.access$listenToSub(Application.kt:1)
    at com.fbistech.ApplicationKt$main$started$1$1.invokeSuspend(Application.kt:96)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:277)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:86)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:61)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at com.fbistech.ApplicationKt$main$started$1.invoke(Application.kt:96)
    at com.fbistech.ApplicationKt$main$started$1.invoke(Application.kt)
    at io.ktor.application.ApplicationEvents.raise(ApplicationEvents.kt:46)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.safeRiseEvent(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:192)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.instantiateAndConfigureApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:311)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.createApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:136)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.start(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:268)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationEngine.start(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:174)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(EngineMain.kt:26)
    at com.fbistech.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:65)
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_osx_x86_64 in java.library.path: /Users/fbistech-d6m/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2447)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:809)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1893)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:371)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:363)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:341)
        ... 46 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Could you please post an error message with a stack trace?

Comment: I have added logs @AlekseiTirman

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce an error from your logs. I've found a similar issue here https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-java/issues/128.